# Confidence interval in python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution, probability-density

Is there a function or a package in python to get the 95% or 99% confidence interval of the distributions present in scipy.stats.

If not what is easiest alternative for that

Here are the distributions (but my priority is halfgennorm and loglaplace)

```
    st.alpha,st.anglit,st.arcsine,st.beta,st.betaprime,st.bradford,st.burr,st.cauchy,st.chi,st.chi2,st.cosine,
    st.dgamma, st.dweibull,st.erlang,st.expon,st.exponnorm,st.exponweib,st.exponpow,st.f,st.fatiguelife,st.fisk,
    st.foldcauchy,st.foldnorm,st.frechet_r,st.frechet_l,st.genlogistic,st.genpareto,st.gennorm,st.genexpon,
    st.genextreme,st.gausshyper,st.gamma,st.gengamma,st.genhalflogistic,st.gilbrat,st.gompertz,st.gumbel_r,
    st.gumbel_l,st.halfcauchy,st.halflogistic,st.halfnorm,st.halfgennorm,st.hypsecant,st.invgamma,st.invgauss,
    st.invweibull,st.johnsonsb,st.johnsonsu,st.ksone,st.kstwobign,st.laplace,st.levy,st.levy_l,st.levy_stable,
    st.logistic,st.loggamma,st.loglaplace,st.lognorm,st.lomax,st.maxwell,st.mielke,st.nakagami,st.ncx2,st.ncf,
    st.nct,st.norm,st.pareto,st.pearson3,st.powerlaw,st.powerlognorm,st.powernorm,st.rdist,st.reciprocal,
    st.rayleigh,st.rice,st.recipinvgauss,st.semicircular,st.t,st.triang,st.truncexpon,st.truncnorm,st.tukeylambda,
    st.uniform,st.vonmises,st.vonmises_line,st.wald,st.weibull_min,st.weibull_max,st.wrapcauchy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get confidence intervals from the percent point function (inverse of the cumulative distribution function). You can do something like the following to get lower and upper confidence bounds of a distribution:

```
lower = rv_continuous.ppf(alpha/2.)
upper = rv_continuous.ppf(1.-alpha/2.)
```

[rv_continuous can be any of the distributions in `scipy.stats`.]

Answer (score 1):

here

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.stats.proportion_confint(906, 906+2066)
```